# How to convert my object detection dataset to Tensorflow specific COCO format (same from Tensorflow datasets)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tfrecord, coco

I’m running this Tensorflow implementation of [Retinanet](https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/) and it ran perfectly. However, **my goal is to adapt it to my own Object Detection dataset i.e. put my own object detection dataset to it.**

The problem is that the author gets COCO dataset using **tfds.load()**
I explored these TFRecords files and I noticed that their image annotations are in a different way (different from default COCO annotations) as shown in the image below:
[annotation comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJet4.jpg)

Colab with error:
Is there a way to generate **TFRecords files in this specific format of annotations for my own dataset** (not get a ready-to-use dataset from tfds)?

Colab with error: https://github.com/allansdefreitas/Deep-Learning-Experiments/blob/master/retinanet_coco_error.ipynb

Thanks a lot!